# How can i set default value for the parameter in magento?

Tags: magento, parameters, get

How can i set default value for the parameter of method get in magento ?

$page_num=($this->getRequest()->getParam('page')) ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('page'):0;

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`$page_num = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page', 0); // 0 - default value`

Answer (score 1):

The second argument is the default return value, it can be anything you like.